# Iterating each row of Data Frame using pySpark

Tags: python, dataframe, iteration, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to iterate over a `dataframe` using pySpark just like we can iterate a set of values using for loop. Below is the code I have written. The problem with this code is

1. I have to use collect which breaks the parallelism
2. I am not able to print any values from the DataFrame in the function `funcRowIter`
3. I cannot break the loop once I have the match found.

I have to do it in pySpark and cannot use pandas for this :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
from pyspark.sql import functions
from pyspark.sql import DataFrameWriter
from pyspark.sql.readwriter import DataFrameWriter
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext()
hive_context = HiveContext(sc)

tab = hive_context.sql("select * from update_poc.test_table_a")

tab.registerTempTable("tab")
print type(tab)

df = tab.rdd

def funcRowIter(rows):
    print type(rows)
        if(rows.id == "1"):
            return 1

df_1 = df.map(funcRowIter).collect()
print df_1
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `df_1 = df.map(funcRowIter).collect()` you should try UDF. Hope this will help.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import struct
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
def funcRowIter(rows):
    print type(rows)
    if(row is nor None and row.id is not None)
        if(rows.id == "1"):
            return 1
A = udf(funcRowIter, ArrayType(StringType()))
z = df.withColumn(data_id, A(struct([df[x] for x in df.columns])))
z.show()
```

`collect()` will never be the good options for very big data i.e millions of records

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your goal is to display a specific row.
You could use`.filter` then a `.collect`.

For instance,

```
row_1 = rdd.filter(lambda x: x.id==1).collect()
```

However, it won't be efficient to try iterate over your dataframe this way.

Comment: I am trying to do this without collect() coz collect will break the parallelism